# WooCommerce Credit Card Fees

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to figure out how to add a product fee that's based on the credit card the customer uses.

For example, if they pay VISA or MasterCard, I must charge an extra 3%. If they pay American Express, I have to add 5%.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I do it? I am unable to use the WooCommerce Extra Charge for Payment Gateway (Standard) plugin as there are no options in the backend.

Comment: Please you should search before asking… This question has already been answered.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

You can use a the [WooCommerce Extra Charges To Payment Gateway](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-extra-charges-to-payment-gateways/) plug-in

On the `Total custom Fixed field` choose `Total % add`

Comment: Where do I find the field you are referencing? I don't see a Checkout tab in WooCommerce's settings.

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle You need to install the plug-in. take a look at the "CONFIGURATION" section in the link.

Comment: It says to click on the Checkout tab, though I don't see this.

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle Did you unzip into your /wp-content/plugins/ directory and activated the plugin through the ‘Plugins’ menu in WordPress?

Comment: I installed this plugin through Wordpress itself.

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle You don't see it under woocommerce tabs?  Please share screen shot

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle http://pluginsmaker.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/woocommerce-credimax-payment-gateway-settings-page.jpg

Comment: These are the tabs that I see: https://ibb.co/jnO87e

Comment: @JeremyMyrtle You could be running another version. Ask in the woocoomerce support or search between the tabs. Sometimes they move things around but it should be there. https://woocommerce.com/contact-us/

Comment: I downloaded the plugin but cannot find the settings. I looked them up and they said that the plugin options were moved to the payments tab, but they still arent there. Not sure where to go now.