# Adding Two Fees in a Single Payment Gateway in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need help adding a processing fee that is based on the credit card my customers use. For example, if they have a VISA card or MasterCard, I'd like to charge 3%. Also if they have an American Express card, then I'd like to charge 5%.

I can't seem to find a plugin that can do this nor do I know any code to write this. This is in the same payment gateway, not two seperate ones.

What can I do and is this possible?

Comment: You can have different fees based on the chosen payment gateway, but not really based on the card type (as you can't detect the chosen card type that is going to generate the fee amount)… Also each payment gateway is different and most of them redirect you to an external page where customer process his payment. Anyway if this is possible, it has to be made by a developer which will need a complete access to your web site. This can not be answered on StackOverFlow as it is a very custom real development.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WooCommerce Credit Card Fees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968638/woocommerce-credit-card-fees)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You unable to control payment type on a bank/processing side, so you need to deal with it on your side (before payment processing).

IMHO there is no way to do this with one payment gateway on your side. I see two options:

1. If your payment gateway is able to split payment types to different gateways (f.ex we have Yandex.Money gateway with such abilities), then it possible to add fees to a gateway by code.
2. If your bank/payment solution is able to select what payment types is allowed to use on your account then you can use two separate gateways with two different accounts.